# Settings activity has leaked IntentReceiver - missing unregisterReceiver()?

Tags: c#, android, android-activity, xamarin.android

In my android app, the user is headed to Notification Access settings to enable the NotificationListenerService. This is made through a simple button which starts a new activity when it's clicked:

```
var intent = new Intent();
intent.SetAction(Android.Provider.Settings.ActionNotificationListenerSettings);
intent.SetFlags(ActivityFlags.NewTask);

MainActivity.Instance.StartActivity(intent);
```

So far so good. The problem comes when the user presses the return button on the device to return to the app. At this point, I see in the logs an IntentReceiverLeaked error:

```
ActivityThread  android.app.IntentReceiverLeaked: Activity com.android.settings.Settings$NotificationAccessSettingsActivity
has leaked IntentReceiver com.android.settings.accounts.AuthenticatorHelper@f52224
that was originally registered here. Are you missing a call to unregisterReceiver()?
at android.app.LoadedApk$ReceiverDispatcher.<init>(LoadedApk.java:1030)
at etc...
```

I found many answers about unregister the broadcast receiver, e.g. once the activity is paused. The problem is that I did not create NotificationAccessSettingsActivity, so I think I cannot unregister the receiver for that action.

It is worth noting that if I press home button and then I return to my app, no error occurs in my logs.

How can I solve this error?

Comment: In the stacktrace, there is no mention to my application package. This makes me think it's a system error, but I'm not completely sure. BTW, I'm testing my app on Android 6.0 (API 23)

Comment: Did you register anywhere else?

Comment: No, I have no broadcast receiver set up in my application.